# Show that it is a point reflection at $A$.

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, rotations, reflection, geometric-transformation

We have the points $Z=(-1,1)$, $A=(-1,6)$ and $B=(3,4)$.

Let $\delta$ be the rotation with center $Z$ and $\delta (A)=B$.

Let $C$ be the point on the circumcircle of the triangle $ABZ$ such that the segment $\overline{CZ}$ goes through the center of circumcircle.

Let $\gamma$ be a rotation with center $C$ and $\gamma (B)=A$.

Show that $\gamma\circ\delta$ is a point reflection at $A$.

To show that do we have to show that there is exactly one fixed point? Or do we have to determine the matrices of the transformation and consider th determinant of the matrix?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: There is a theorem which says:

If $\mathcal R_M$ and $\mathcal R_N$ are two rotations around $M$ respectively $N$ for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ then their composite $\mathcal R = \mathcal R_N\circ\mathcal R_M$ is rotation around new point $S$ for $\alpha+\beta $ where $S$ is in triangle $MNS$ with $\angle SMN= \alpha/2$ and $\angle MNS = \beta/2$.

Comment: But in this case we want to show that the composition is a point reflection. Do we have to express the rotation as a point reflection to use this theorem?

Comment: What is reflection about point?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_reflection

Comment: So at a point reflection, we reflect over a specific point.

Comment: This means that there is exactly one fixed point, or not? If we show that there is exactly one fixed point, do we get then the desired result?